# How to use LIKE for type int and data

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a database (SQL server) with a table of students in which there are fields Name (nvarchar (50)), Age (int) and Birthday (date). I added this database in C # windows forms. I do a search by name:

```
bindingSource.Filter = "Name LIKE'" + textBox5.Text + "%'";
```

And it works well. But this does not work with the Age field:

```
bindingSource.Filter = "Age LIKE'" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) + "%'";
```

Can anyone else know how to do the same for the Birthday field?

Comment: Before anything, stop injecting your values. Always parametrise your queries. What you have right now is a huge security flaw.

Comment: Age is an integer, you can't compare it with a string. You should probably convert/cast the Age column to a string and compare.

Comment: On the subject of your question, you can't use a `LIKE` against a numerical data type, it has to be a string type. What is your end goal here? Seems like you should instead be using `BETWEEN` logic. Instead of `Age LIKE '3%'`, I assume you really want `AGE BETWEEN 30 AND 39` or `Age >= 30 AND Age < 40`.

Comment: Careful @VTChiew , that *could* ruin the performance. Plus it would seem odd that `'3%'` should return ages 3 and 30-39. :/

Comment: If I were your instructor, I'd test your code by searching for a student with a name like `';DROP TABLE Students;--`

Comment: Or you could just send your son "Little Bobby Tables" to the school @DanGuzman  https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Wait, does the Filter allow you to pass in database commands?

Comment: @CharlesMay, I'm sure that's not the intent but what can happen with non-parameterized queries.I wish instructors would teach that better.

Comment: @DanGuzman But my question is, this isn't an SQL statement, it's a Filter use to limit the results of the dataset, how does one use a parameter with it? I'm actually setting up some tests right now to see if it's possible

Comment: @CharlesMay, it's not only possible but quite common. The parameterized query `SELECT * FROM dbo.Students WHERE Name LIKE @Name + '%d;` will search for names beginning with the specified parameter value. With a `SqlCommand` object, the parameter value could be added with `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name"`, SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = textBox5.Text;'

Comment: @DanGuzman. I totally understand, BUT again, this is a `.Filter` on a bindingsource. How would you supply this with a parameter to protect it from SQL Injection attacks? And mostly, IS SQL Injection possible in this context?

Comment: `BindingSource.Filter` has nothing to do with SQL Injection. Just use convert function like the duplicate post.

Comment: Thank you all, I found a solution:   bindingSource.Filter = "CONVERT(Age, 'System.String') LIKE'%" + textBox5.Text + "%'";

Comment: @CharlesMay, I see what you are saying is that this is a client-side filter and SQL injection is not relevant (although one would have a problem searching for a value like "O'Hare"). That said, a parameterized query on the underlying would be better solution IMHO to avoid loading the entire student database into memory.

Answer (score 0):

For numeric columns, use equals `=`.  If you really do want to search `Age` by a partial value, then you'll need to cast it to a character value first.

```
studentsBindingSource.Filter = "CAST([Age] AS varchar) LIKE '" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + "%'";`
```

Be sure to first validate that the user entered a numeric value into textBox3.

Note that I'm only directly answering your question.  Using parameterized queries will prevent SQL injection attacks, and should be the preferred way of handing it.

Comment: This is still injecting values (although at least an integer is a "safe(r)" value; but doesn't solve the problem with (the not well named) `textbox5`.

Comment: Input validation is good but parameterized queries are better.